# git moving from dev to master (prod)

Tags: git, github

We're ready to push our dev branch to our prod (master) branch but I wanted to see if there was a best practices on doing this.  Seems too easy to just git push dev master.

Right now our prod (master) is tagged 1.0 and dev is going to be master 1.5.

Should we simply push dev master and tag?  Some have mentioned rebasing but not sure...

Comment: "Pushing" won't help you here. You need to **merge**. Running `git push dev master` is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing your nomenclature here. git push moves changes from one repository to another. What I think you mean is merge your dev branch into your prod branch. The `git push dev master` command you suggest is thus confusing. I believe Git would interpret this as push branch `master` to repository `dev`.

I'm also a bit confused as to what result you're looking for with the tagging. I think what you're saying is once you merge dev into prod and release, prod will be tagged '1.5'. In this case, you're looking for:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
git tag -a 1.5 -m "<your message here>"
git push <your remote repo here> --all
git push <your remote repo here> --tags
```

Rebasing is just a strategy to make your history look a bit more pretty, but it sounds like you have bigger things to worry about.

Comment: FYI: `\`backticks\`` denote inline code. There is no need to use `\`\`\`triple backticks\`\`\``.

Comment: This makes sense.  Many times when we would push/pull it would detect an overlap and (auto) merge (asking us for some additional comments).  I figured this would (auto) happen when we would do our push to master (from dev).  Again, this makes sense and we'll move forward with this.  Thanks!